# Running complex query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read multiple answers about this but still cannot manage to do it.

So i have table like this:

**TABLE 1**

```
| ID     |  COL1    |  COL2    |
| 1      |  10      |  Item_1  |
| 2      |  10      |  Item_2  |
| 3      |  10      |  Item_3  |
| 4      |  11      |  Item_2  |
| 4      |  11      |  Item_4  |
| 5      |  12      |  Item_1  |
| 6      |  12      |  Item_3  |
```

First i need to run this command `SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL2 = ITEM2 GROUP BY COL1`
This command returns me `10` and `11`

Now after that i need to run this: `SELECT COUNT(ID) AS 'COUNT', COL2 from TABLE1 group by COL2 order by 'COUNT' DESC LIMIT 5` and here i need to add `WHERE` statement so it doesn't run on whole table but only where `COL1 = any result from first selection`

So second command would return something like this:

```
2    Item_2
1    Item_1
1    Item_3
1    Item_4
```

So how can i achieve this from one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter in the `where`:

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.ID) AS cnt, COL2 
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.COL1 IN (SELECT TT1.COL1
                  FROM TABLE1 TT1
                  WHERE TT1.COL2 = 'ITEM2'
                 )
GROUP BY T1.COL2 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Note that `IN` removes duplicates, so `GROUP BY` (or `SELECT DISTINCT`) are not needed.

Comment: This one works.... didn't know that `in()` could be used like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
    select col2,count(*) as cnt from table
    where condition 1st query
    group by col2
order by cnt 
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(id) as Count_name,
    col_2 
FROM 
    Count_54
WHERE 
    col_1 in (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT col_1 
        FROM
            Count_54 
        WHERE
            col_2='Item_2'
    )
GROUP BY 
    col_2 
ORDER BY 
    col_1 DESC;
```